# How can I generate a redstone signal without using redstone power components?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to design some redstone puzzles that require unconventional solutions.

Is there a way to generate a redstone signal that does not rely on any [redstone power components](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_components#Power_components)? Two years ago I swore I saw a video of someone generating a redstone signal using a block update. Is this possible?

Comment: Unless you count redstone ore blocks, no. You could use a block update to power a piston (BUD switch), but you need a piston for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparators put against any container will output a signal at a strength equal to the percentage filled the container is - one notable combo is to use a cauldron filled with water, which is also able to move, and produces a signal with a strength of 15 when placed behind a comparator.

In terms of block updates, you could probably modify the normal BUD that uses a redstone block to instead use a cauldron-comparator combo, but it won't be particularly space efficient.

I've added some pictures of a proof of concept below.  It basically takes the one wide tileable design from [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Block_update_detector#Piston_Based) page and replaces the redstone blocks and the redstone torch with filled cauldrons.

[image: No-Power BUD Side 1]

[image: No-Power BUD Side 2]

[image: No-Power BUD Top]